# Index was outside the bounds of the array at printing process

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, rdlc

I use [PerpetuumSoft](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Home.aspx?lang=en) to print multiple reports but I get the following exception:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.Stack Trace :at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.StringCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
```

---

my code :

```
  PrintReportSample.ReportPrintDocument RP = new PrintReportSample.ReportPrintDocument(lectReport);                     
  string pr = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[1].ToString();
  RP.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pr;
  RP.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
  RP.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 11;
  RP.Print();
```

---

I want to recognize the default printer for the client, not the server.

I face this problem only on the server, everything goes okay locally !!

---

## EDIT :

According to the answers :

```
string pr = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[0].ToString();
```

It loads long time and nothing is happen at all and I don't get any exceptions?

---

Locally When I try to print, Save `XPS` document window" appears

Comment: `InstalledPrinters[1]` should be `InstalledPrinters[0]`

Comment: And you should check `.InstalledPrinters.Any()` or `.InstalledPrinters.Length > 0` to verify that there is, in fact, an installed printer before trying to use it.

Comment: yeah this code works locally but  i get this exception when publishing . i try index of `0` but it takes long time then i get `request time out ` after long time !!!

Comment: If this is asp, not silverlight, won't the check go for the servers printers instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pull a value from an array element that does not exist, in this line here.

```
string pr = 
  System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[1].ToString();
```

You're making an assumption that the InstalledPrinters property has at least two values in it.

I also suspect that you should be looking at the first element in the array.

```
string pr = 
  System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[0].ToString();
```

Either way, you should defensively check whether the value exists before using it.

```
if ( System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters != null && 
     System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count > 0 )
{
   // Do your work here
}
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[1].ToString();` works locally but i get this exception when i publish , i try the index `0` just `....Waiting` then time out !!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user has *any* installed printers and if you want, take the first (Index 0!). You just take the second printer no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it seems like, you have OutOfBound issue for the printer you are selecting to print. Collection/Array in c# Are zero bound index.

Additionally, you should even make sure that there are `printer(s)` installed.

So,

```
InstalledPrinters[1]
```

should be

```
//assuming that there is at least one printer installed
InstalledPrinters[0]
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[1].ToString();` works locally but i get this exception when i publish , i try the index `0` just `....Waiting` then time out !!!